# C#- network adapter disable/enable

Tags: c#, network-programming, adapter

I am learning c# and I wrote this code:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    ManagementObject mObj = new ManagementObject("\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2:Win32_NetworkAdapter.NetConnectionID=\"Wireless Network Connection\"");
    mObj.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.ManagementException'
>   occurred in System.Management.dll

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First question on such low-level tweaks: are you running at "Run as administrator" mode?